# How does angular2 tutorial 'tour of heroes' achive url path rewrite without conflicts

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, redirect, angular2-routing

I've been studying to use angular2 following the official tutorial -- "tour of heroes". I know that it directs all url paths to the root '/' so that index.html in the root directory can get the path info for angular router. While I noticed that it also rewrites the url path for APIs on the back-end, such as using "get( 'app/heroes/id')" to get data from the API. What confused me is how does angular2 or node.js achieve that? Since the server has directed every path to the root, then how does front-end side make request to the APIs on back-end, I don't understand why there is no conflicts in the tutorial while I think there should be. For example, if I make a request to an API on back-end, since url path has been rewritten and directed to the root, then my request will be directed to the root directory too not to the API, am I right? Anyone can teach me the principles behind this in Angular2 please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's really no magic behind it. In node.js you can create *catch all* route that will handle any request for which there's no handler defined. So you can define routes like `/app/heroes/id` and serve required content, this route has higher priority then *catch all* route. Then for example in *express framework* for node.js you can define *catch all* route `/*` and always return index.html file while the URL in address bar remains unchanged for example when you type to address bar example.com/heroes/id and hit enter then server serves index.html then angular reads the URL and displays requir

Comment: ed page. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the help! So you mean the APIs route has higher priority than the index.html route? But when I type "/app/heroes/id" in the address bar and hit enter I got an error message saying "cannot match any routes". While I can "get" it using http method, why is that please?@Molda

Comment: The example doesn't call the server route at all. They use https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Got it, thanks again! @Molda